# Running Node.js app and PHP in same machine

Tags: php, node.js, amazon-ec2, virtualhost

I am really confused whether it is possible ? Please help me out, I have Node.js application, say node_app, running on X port, and PHP application, say my_app, running in Apache's default 80 port. I have one domain name only. What my problem is, if user hit **domain.com/my_app**, it should run the PHP application in 80's port. If the user hits **domain.com/node_app**, it should run the node application in X port. And one more important constraint is the end-user **should not see any port number in URL bar**.

Comment: You can have apache setup to proxy requests that come through a specific path to another port on your machine such as a node server. However that is probably something for [server fault](http://serverfault.com/) because it has more to do with networking and server management instead of programming which is what SO is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Node.JS and PHP in the same host, using Nginx as proxy per exemple.

Per exemple, with Nginx, you could create two virtualhosts :

- Default virtual host using PHP (FPM or not) who points to exemple.tld
- Second virtual host to another node.exemple.tld

First VH is gonna be like this (with PHP-FPM) :

```
server {
        listen   80; ## listen ipv4 port 80

        root /www;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from exemple.tld
        server_name exemple.tld;

        location / {
          try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000 and using HHVM or PHP
        #
        location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_keep_conn on;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Second VH with NodeJS :

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name node.exemple.tld;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        access_log off;

        # Assuming that NodeJS listen to port 8888, change if it is listening to another port!
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888/;
        proxy_redirect off;

        # Socket.IO Support if needed uncomment
        #proxy_http_version 1.1;
        #proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        #proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    # IF YOU NEED TO PROXY A SOCKET ON A SPECIFIC DIRECTORY
    location /socket/ {
        # Assuming that the socket is listening the port 9090
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9090;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's possible, and pretty easy to do!

Comment: I'm not sure, whether it will work, because I never used Nginx, but it is very clear, anyone can understand just by reading this. Sorry, I don't much reputation to up vote for you.

Comment: No problem, it's a pleasure @VijayAnand